# highcharts - error in IE - Invalid Argument

Tags: internet-explorer-8, highcharts, invalid-argument

I am getting an error in IE as:

Message: Invalid argument.
Line: 8
Char: 56
Code: 0
URI: .../js/highcharts.js

Below is the highcharts chart code..It works perfectly fine in Firefox but in IE throws an error.Can anybody help me with this. Thanks.

```
    function drawChart(categories,series){
       $('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        backgroundColor:'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1)',
        spacingLeft: -2
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: categories,
        gridLineWidth:0.5,
        labels: {
            style: {
                fontSize:'0px'
            }
    }
    },
    colors: ["#a7c1d0"],
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            marker: {
                enabled: false
            }
        }
    },
    title: {
        text: "Last 45 days NAV Price",
            align: 'center',
            style:{
                color: '#5e605e',
                fontSize:'11px',
                fontFamily:'Arial'
            },
            y:1
    },
    legend: {
    enabled:false
        },
        navigation: {
            buttonOptions: {
                enabled: false
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
              title: {
                    enabled: true,
                    text: 'Price',
                    style: {
                        color: '#5e605e',
                        fontSize:'10px',
                        marginLeft:'-5px;',
                        fontFamily:'Arial'
                    }
                },
            labels:{
                style:{
                    fontSize:'10px'
                },


                step:0,
            },
            lineWidth: 1,
            tickInterval: 0.20,
            minTickInterval:0.20
        },
    series: [{
        data: series     
    }]
});
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you paste your data? Moreever you have i.e extra common in labels object.

```
labels:{
            style:{
                fontSize:'10px'
            },


            step:0,
        },
```

http://www.highcharts.com/docs/frequently-asked-questions#not-showing-in-explorer

Comment: hi, this is my data..categories: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36]  and the series: [14.95520266, 14.95519763, 14.95519252, 14.95570493, 14.98247948, 15.01307267, 15.08519138, 15.09196832, 15.09196315, 15.09195799, 15.09966966, 15.11531496, 15.12384567, 15.12751832, 15.1275256, 15.12752554, 15.122, 15.09, 15.07050232, 15.06363029, 15.05623958, 15.050, 15.06, 15.0715, 15.0821627, 15.08, 15.05259583, 15.04, 15.04, 15.048, 15.0, 15.0569, 15.05974165, 15.059, 15.05946, 15.05947105, 15.05947124]

Comment: First of all please fix extra commmas, then let us know if it will not work.

Comment: i fixed the comma in the labels..and yet no success... any other extra commas which i overlooked?

Comment: I found where i was going wrong...there was a semicolon after the  marginLeft:'-5px;',....fixed it..thanks for all the help :)